# Vertical index for TableViewControllers

Tags: search, indexing, uitableview

It may be quite easy to do, but I can't find out how:

I want to add a vertical index in my sorted `UITableViewController`, like in the "Contacts" application.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found how to make it.
With a [UILocalizedIndexedCollation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalizedIndexedCollation_Class/UILocalizedIndexedCollation.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILocalizedIndexedCollation), there is a sample in [tableViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableViewSuite/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318).

I followed the source code, then it works perfectly.